How to stop 2 threads in 1 function
I have some program that communicates with the user. The program should terminate when the user has entered a sample text.
import time
import threading

def printer():
    while True:
        print("Message")
        time.sleep(30)

def getter():
    while True:
        text = str(input())
        if text == "sample_text":
            print("It's sample text")


thread1 = threading.Thread(target=printer)
thread1.start()
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=getter)
thread2.start()

How to terminate both threads in getter function

Python threading is problematic because it disables signals for all but the main thread. So, even though a platform level sleep in a thread can be canceled with a signal, that doesn't work in python.
You need some sort of mechanism to do your own signalling to the thread. The most basic is a shared variable that threads know to wake and poll. A step up is an Event that threads can use to wait. But if your thread is off waiting on other things, it gets problematic. Waiting on a socket? Well, maybe the main thread can know to close the socket. But if you want to wake the thread without closing the socket... that gets complicated. Maybe your socket recv can have a timeout and you can do the periodic poll thing. Maybe you can go non blocking and use select or one if its kin. Maybe you'd be better off using python's asyncio services.
You already have a great answer using Event, but this answer is more on the "its complicated" side. This is no one-size-fits-all to this question. There are many design decisions to be made.

There is no straightforward way to kill a thread from outside itself in Python. You have to resort to a messaging mechanism (could be as simple as a global variable which is assigned to True when all threads should stop), and all threads have to actively check the message, and stop themselves (by either raising an exception, or returning from their entry-point function).
In this case, this means that instead of sleep(30) you'd have to interleave periodic checking for the exit condition:

import time
import threading

STOP_THREADS = False

def printer():
    while not STOP_THREADS:
        print("Message")
        time.sleep(1)

def getter():
    global STOP_THREADS  # Only functions that will modify a variable need to declare it as globl.
    while True:
        text = str(input())
        if text == "sample_text":
            print("It's sample text")
            STOP_THREADS = True


thread1 = threading.Thread(target=printer)
thread1.start()
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=getter)
thread2.start()




This works, but an event would be more responsive without the (admittedly small) system performance hit of waking threads.

There is no way of "not waking a thread" in Python. What could be done is one or more worker threads each running an asyncio loop - that way, the system threads would be always running, and when waiting for input for specific tasks, the same thread would still be used for other threads.This approach also makes it trivial to have a small asynchronous task that just monitors for a termination signal, so the actual code can be written without worrying about any active checking.

the standard way is using a threading.Event object, and waiting on it instead of sleeping.
import time
import threading

stop = threading.Event()


def printer():
    while not stop.is_set():
        print("Message")
        stop.wait(30)

def getter():
    while not stop.is_set():
        text = str(input())
        if text == "sample_text":
            print("It's sample text")
            stop.set()


thread1 = threading.Thread(target=printer)
thread1.start()
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=getter)
thread2.start()
thread1.join()
thread2.join()

yes, you will need to check that the event is set manually.
I once wrapped it in a class that would throw an exception if you checked the event and it was set, this way i can escape multiple stack frames when i need to terminate the thread, it is not a best practice as it uses exceptions for control flow, but it works and python already uses it in iterators and exit() and many other functions, so it is actually pythonic !
